# headphone with active noise cancelling, mic, earhook, wired and not too expansive

Tags: headphones, headset

I've been looking for a new headset for office, but can't find any that suit the following requirement :

- Need a good microphone
- Has active noise cancelling
- Isn't worn on the head like most headset
- Is wired USB or 3.5mm
  This excludes all bluetooth headset.
  USB connection is preferred but both USB and 3.5mm are good
- Affordable (must be below 120 USD)
- Headphones with only one ear aren't suitable
- The speaker doesn't go deep within the ear.
  For clarity, the following image show which type of speaker this criteria exclude.

### [image: bad example]

- Ideally, they need some kind of support that prevent them from falling off when moving the head. This support would preferably be a big or small hook around the ear.

Here is an example that would be suitable if it existed :

### [image: Good example]

Are there headphones that match these criteria? If yes, can point them out?

Answer (score 4):

You've got two conflicting criteria: noise cancelling and shallow in the ear. Anything noise cancelling is also going to be as noise isolating as possible to avoid letting in excess sound to minimize the job the active cancellation needs to do.

The best I can recommend would be something from [Bose's in-ear lineup.](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/earphones.html) They've all got inline mics and wired 3.5mm options, and of course, active noise cancelling.

The [SoundSport](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/earphones/soundsport-in-ear-headphones-apple-devices.html#v=soundsport_ie_headphones_ii_apple_energy_green) and [SoundTrue](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/earphones/soundtrue-ultra-in-ear-headphones-apple-devices.html#v=soundtrue_ultra_apple_charcoal) both offer most of what you're asking for and aren't super expensive (around the $50-100 point), but only offer okay noise cancelling. The SoundTrue sounds slightly better while costing more.

[image]

The [QuietComfort 20s](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/headphones/earphones/quietcomfort-20i-acoustic-noise-cancelling-headphones.html#v=qc20_apple_black) offer much better noise cancelling, but are well out of your budget ($200-250 pricepoint)–however, if you're willing to [buy used](https://us.bidvoy.net/QuietComfort_20/112529) or from a third party, they might be a good option.

[image]

I haven't personally used the SoundSport or SoundTrue and am basing my suggestions on comparisons to headphones I do own. I own the QC20s and (though I do enjoy them) prefer over-ears, so they don't get an immense amount of use.

Comment: The Bose SounTrue's MSRP on newegg is supposed to be $120 MSRP (top range of OP), but is on sale right now for [$79 (limited offer expiring on dec 25th)](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826627055). They are a great option, however.